# How can I transfer my contacts from iPhone to MacBook?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, contacts

I don't know why I'm unable to do such a simple thing, I have tried everything which I could find on [Google search.](https://www.easeus.com/iphone-data-transfer/import-contacts-from-iphone-to-mac-with-without-itunes.html) I want to transfer all my contacts from my iPhone to my Mac so that I can manage duplicate contacts.

Why Apple doesn't allow  such an easy thing to be done with ease? Why I'm not allowed to move my contacts from iPhone to my computer.

Problems I'm getting:

1. **The iCloud method**: In my iPhone when I got to Settings -> My Name -> iCloud -> Contacts. The "Contacts" is already on, and I don't know what to do next.
2. **The iTunes Method**: When I click on "info"  in iTunes tab (after clicking on my iPhone icon) I get something written like "Your contacts are shared over air via iCloud" (I don't remember the verbatim).

Please help me.

Comment: Are your contacts stored on your iPhone or in your iCloud account? If you add a new contact on your iPhone does it show up on your Mac?
Are you logged in to the same iCloud account on your Mac and your iPhone?

Comment: Yes, I’m logged in same account in my iPhone and Mac. Should I save a dummy contact and see if it appears in icloud or Mac?

Answer (score 1):

> The iCloud method: In my iPhone when I got to Settings -> My Name -> iCloud -> Contacts. The "Contacts" is already on, and I don't know what to do next.

You need two devices to sync. So on Mac too, in System Preferences > iCloud, turn on Contacts sync.

Check Contacts.app > Preferences to see that account is enabled.

I don't know about iTunes method.

> so that I can manage duplicate contacts.

That is not easy on Mac either. What I do is:

- On Mac, export all contacts in a vcf file.
- Upload it on https://contacts.google.com and then let it find the duplicates.
- Sort out the duplicates locally and verify it again.
- Select all contacts on the Google web interface & delete them.

Comment: How to get contacts on Mac in order to create a VCF card?

Comment: @Knight **1** did you turn on Contacts sync in Mac iCloud settings ? **2** did you check Mac contacts.app preferences to see that the account is enabled?

Comment: Yes to both questions :-)

Comment: Check on iCloud web to find out where's the problem. If you see contacts on the web, the Mac is at fault. If you don't see them there, iPhone haven't uploaded them yet.

Comment: I have created a dummy contact, it is not appearing neither on iCloud, nor on Mac.

Comment: Although, I have everything "ON" in my iPhone, settings -> iCloud -> contacts -> ON 
Settings -> Contacts -> Default Account -> iCloud.

Comment: So the iPhone can be in low power mode, cellular is disabled for iCloud sync, cellular is disabled for contacts app. connect the phone to wifi & it'll work.

Comment: It is connected to WIFI.

Comment: I'm out of guesses :(